# Same device and vendor id of two pci card on two different slots - x86

Tags: linux

I am working with the PCI, i am using two pci cards with same device id and vendor 
    id on two different slots on different buses.
    we are inserting the same pci driver for both devices, only one driver is getting inserted
    when i tried to do insert the driver my change the device name, it is file already exists.

```
Is any possibility to use the same driver to use for both devices without modifying the device id and vendor id on PCI card.
```

Thank You

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by inserting driver the second time? Are you trying to run `modprobe` twice?

Comment: ya, but by changing the device name